# Median filter produces unexpected result on FITS file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, mask

This is based on a couple of other questions that haven't quite been answered, so I've started a new post. I'm working on finding the median of a masked array in 50-pixel patches. The image and the mask are both 901x877 telescope images.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits

#   Use the fits files as input image and mask
hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')
w1data = hdulist[0].data
hdulist3 = fits.open('xbulge-mask.fits')
mask = 1 - hdulist3[0].data
w1masked = np.ma.array(w1data, mask = mask)

#   Use general arrays as input image and mask
#w1data = np.arange(790177).reshape(901,877)
#w1masked = np.ma.masked_inside(w1data, 30000, 60000)


side = 50                                                                                                                                                                                
w, h = w1data.shape                                                                                                                                                                                            
width_index   = np.array(range(w//side)) * side                                                                                                                                                             
height_index  = np.array(range(h//side)) * side                                                                                                                                                             

def assign_patch(patch, median, side):                                                                                                                                                                     
    """Break this loop out to prevent 4 nested 'for' loops"""                                                                                                                                              
    for j in range(side):                                                                                                                                                                                  
        for i in range(side):                                                                                                                                                                              
            patch[i,j] = median                                                                                                                                                                            
    return patch                                                                                                                                                                                           

for width in width_index:                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for height in height_index:                                                                                                                                                                            
        patch  = w1masked[width:width+side, height:height+side]                                                                                                                                                  
        median = np.median(patch)                                                                                                                                                                          
        assign_patch(patch, median, side)                                                                           

plt.imshow(w1masked)
plt.show()
```

The problem is, when I use the general arrays as input image and mask (the commented out section), it works fine, but when I use the FITS files, it produces 'side'-sized patches on the output image. I can't figure out what's going on with this.

Comment: You are assigning the same value to all pixels in each patch - what result are you expecting?

Comment: I want each pixel in the patch to be assigned the value of the median of the pixels in the patch, not included any masked pixels. So yes,each pixel in the patch should have the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your FITS files look like but there are several things standing out:

- `np.median` doesn't take the `mask` into account. In fact in recent NumPy releases this (correctly) prints a Warning if attempted. You should be using `np.ma.median` instead. If you would update your NumPy you'll likely see this:

> UserWarning: Warning: 'partition' will ignore the 'mask' of the MaskedArray.

- The `assign_patch` function is unnecessary when you know that you can use slice assignment:

  ```
  w1masked[width:width+side, height:height+side] = median
  # instead of "assign_patch(patch, median, side)"
  ```

That's also much faster than doing a double loop to replace each value.

I assume that the issue is in fact because you use `np.median` instead of `np.ma.median`. There are lots of values a masked pixel could have including `nan`, `0`, `inf`, ... so if these are taken into account (when they should be ignored) could produce any kind of problems, especially if the `median` starts returning `nan`s or similar.

---

More generally if you really wanted a median filter you can't just calculate the median of a patch and replace all values in the patch with that median. You should be using a median filter that takes the mask into account. Unfortunately I've never seen such a filter implemented in any wide-spread Python package. But if you have numba you could checkout a (very experimental!) package of mine [`numbamisc`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/numbamisc) which contains a [`median_filter`](http://numbamisc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#numbamisc._filters.median_filter) that takes masks into account.